# Check if hyperlink in gridview has been clicked c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, arraylist, hyperlink

Hi I would like to know how to get the text field and index from a hyperlink in a gridview that has been clicked. Basically, the user would click on the hyperlink in the gridview and when the user has been navigated to the link, the text field and index of the link would be stored into an arraylist. Does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?

I have came up with this "pseudo code" for the onrowdatabound event handler in gridview:

```
ArrayList linksClicked = new ArrayList();

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("links");
            if (hl != null)
            {
                linksClicked.Add(h1.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ItemTemplate` with `LinkButton`. In this button you can keep index or id like `CommandArgument`, also you easily catch event `onClick` and add index to your array. Use this sample.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="hyperLinkButton" Text="link" PostBackUrl="youruri.com" runat="server" 
           CommandArgument="<%# Eval("SomeFieldYouNeedArguementFrom") %>" OnClick="hyperLinkButton_Click" >
           </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


protected void hyperLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string yourValue = btn.CommandArgument;
    // do what you need here
}
```

Comment: Oh I See, thanks! By the way what if I wanted to open the link in a new tab on the hyperlinkbutton click. What I'm trying to achieve here is this: The user has to click and view each link in the gridview. Upon clicking each link the link will be opened in a new tab and the link that was clicked will be added to a listbox. The user has to complete opening all the links in order to do the next task.